# bit manipulation using int in java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have an int and I want to invert the bits of it using the ~ bit operator. This should be a very simply thing to do, however I tried and it doesn't work. I suppose this is because java uses two's complement to represent it's int. So what is the most efficient way to do this? 50 when inverted should be 13 and that's the value I'd like to have

Comment: 50 only becomes 13 when inverted if you're dealing with 6 bits - an unusual thing to do as `char` is 8 bits. Are you sure you have your target right?

Comment: and 100 is converted to 27. In order words I need to convert this int to a byte array I suppose and invert it

Comment: Please explain why you believe 50 should become 13... are you only trying to invert the bits as far as the highest set bit in the original int?

Comment: @xonegirlz: I don't see where byte arrays come in, nor how you get from 100 to 27, unless (as I say) you only want to invert as many bits as were originally set. Note that this will not be an invertible operation - think about what you'd want the inverse of 27 to be...

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, just want to invert the bits that is originally already set, sorry I should make it a bit clear

Comment: @xonegirlz: So you're aware that when you invert 27 you *won't* get back to 100?

Comment: `int x = (50 ^ 0xFFFFFFFF)` & 0x3F; will give your expected answer but I suspect its not what you're after.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes I am aware in a 32 bit representation two's complement inverting 27 won't get 100.

Comment: @xonegirlz: But neither will your desired inversion - that's my point. If you're only going to invert up to the largest set bit, then *that* bit will necessarily become 0, so inverting the result *won't* invert it back to a 1. Why do you want such an operation, by the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want only the part of the bitwise complement until the most signifficant set bit of the input. Then you just have to mask the complement,

```
int invert(int n) {
    return ~n & mask(n);
}
int mask(int n) {
    n |= n >> 1;
    n |= n >> 2;
    n |= n >> 4;
    n |= n >> 8;
    return n | (n >> 16);
}
```

Comment: would you mind giving me some explanation of the method above

Comment: If n has the k-th bit set, but no higher, mask(n) has bits 0 to k set, (k+1) to 31 unset. By `n |= n >> 1;` for each set bit, the next lower bit is also set, so, for example `0x40` becomes `0x60`, then for each group of two set bits, the next lower group is set by `n |= n >> 2;`, giving `0x78` for the example. Continue doubling the group length of set bits until the group of the highest set bit is guaranteed to include the 0-th bit. Then in invert, we take the full bitwise complement and mask out what we're not interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Java `int` is 32-bit long with 1 bit used for sign.  Therefore 50 is represented in binary as `00000000000000000000000000110010`. If you bit-invert this, you'll get `11111111111111111111111111001101`, which is java integer value -51 in decimal notation.

Answer (score -2):

Since an `int` should be at least 32 bits wide, ~50 is definitely not 13. I think you are assuming the `int` to be only 8 bits wide, which may have been the case some 237 years ago, but definitely not nowadays and not in Java, anyway. If you need a data type that is guaranteed to be 8 bits wide, use `byte`.

But even then ~50 is not 13, only if take the least significant 6 bits into account. But all this doesn't have anything to do with two's complement.